# How do I join two tables ON a column, that has the same name in both tables?

Tags: sql

see above...

Comment: The question should be reformatted. Where's Rich B?

Comment: he's busy stitching on his latest Strunk & White badge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  *
from    Table1
        inner join
        Table2
        on Table1.ColumnName = Table2.ColumnName
```

Simple really.

Comment: With someone who is obviously new, is it a good idea to encourage SELECT * ?

Comment: What else can you say without any hint of the schema?

Comment: I'd suggest "ColumnName" instead of Column, since Column is a keyword. Not that it matters in real SQL, just for example code.

Answer (score 8):

Use an Alias for the table names is the shortest.

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM table1 as 'a'
  INNER JOIN table2 as 'b'
    ON a.col1 = b.col1
```

You can also specify the full table names.

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.*
FROM table1
  INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.col1 = table2.col1
```

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking is called `NATURAL JOIN` in relational terminology. Some database servers support this clause. I would prefer to manually specify the join expression even if the provider supports such a clause like:

```
SELECT .... FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.JoinCol = Table2.JoinCol ...
```

Comment: As an addition to your point, I always specify the table or alias for the table so anyone looking will know exactly where the column comes from. It makes refactoring / maintenance much easier later on.

Answer (score 0):

And for completeness (depending on your DBMS) you could use "USING":

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    table_a
INNER JOIN
    table_b
USING
    (common_column);
```